# Logs of Kafka payload in Table Api connector of Apache Flink

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using the upsert-kafka table API connector of Apache Flink to consume events from a kafka topic, I want to log the kafka payloads that are consumed , is there a way to log it.

My code looks as below:

```
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build();
        TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
String statement = "CREATE TABLE Employee (\r\n" +
"  employee  ROW(id STRING, name STRING\r\n" +
"  ),\r\n" +
"  PRIMARY KEY (employeeId) NOT ENFORCED\r\n" +
") WITH (\r\n" +
"  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',\r\n" +
"  'topic' = 'employee',\r\n" +
"  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" +
"  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" +
"  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',\r\n" +
"  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-cp-schema-registry:8081',\r\n" +
")";
tEnv.executeSql(statement);
```

I added log4j.properties to enable log but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a log4j KafkaAppender, yes, but you'll need to explicitly log the records in the code; using FlinkKafkaConsumer class and manual iterating over the stream, rather than FlinkSQL api

Comment: Thanks for the response @OneCricketeer. If I am not wrong, KafkaAppender is used to write logs to a Kafka topic, so you are suggesting to use it to have the logs captured to a Kafka topic, quite unclear to me. Also just wanted to check if logging is not at all possible if we use the FlinkSQL API?

Comment: I honestly didn't really understand your question. Flink uses log4j, and log4j can write to Kafka... That has nothing to do with creation of FlinkSQL tables. If you want to print the data from the table that you've created, then you need to run a select query, which your question didn't include. Or, as answered, you should use `FlinkKafkaConsumer` to read records, which is different from the Table API

Comment: Apologies @OneCricketeer for any misunderstanding. I got your point on using the ```FlinkKafkaConsumer``` to consume the Kafka records, but since I am already using the Flink SQL API for reading from the Kafka topic , I wanted to know if there are any options that Flink provides to enable logging for the SQL operations (like the insert, update from which I can get the payload of Kafka) similar to how we can enable for hibernate or other ORM frameworks.

Comment: You need to execute a select query. From there, you get a TableResult object you can iterate over and log the rows. The Row object is the closest you'll get to ORM. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/overview/#execute-a-query outside of that, Flink log4j configs may or may not print any given query, I'm not sure, but that's unrelated to Kafka

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I will try the way you have suggested and see if that would give me the expected result.